# How to solve a media query 17px 'delay' in dev tools on a Win 10?

Tags: css, media-queries, devtools

It started with me writing some CSS code and adding media queries which were supposed to fire on max- width 830px. The media query works, only it fires on 813px. There is no other media query for that element, so nothing is overwriting it, and it behaves as expected, only 17 pixels later. This occurred on a Windows 10 laptop (fully updated) on a Chrome Browser. I tested on Firefox and the results were the same: media query fires on 813px instead of 830px. Same results on Brave as well.

I tested it on a Mac (also on Chrome), and there the Dev Tools showed the media query fired correctly on 830px. But, I can't make it work on my Win 10 laptop.

So far I tried:

- different browsers, on my laptop (Chrome, Firefox, Brave), in all of them there is the 17px difference;
- the viewport tag is correct (meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
- the browser zoom level is correct (tested it multiple times, on multiple browsers, all set on 100%);
- changed and tried all combinations of DPI settings for the Chrome app on my laptop, without any results;
- changed the scale and layout percentage in windows display settings, and it didn't change anything in the browser.

The same issue persists, with any random web page I inspect online. I will select an element which has media query code on it, and there is always a 17px delay from the actual size on which it is supposed to fire.

Any ideas or advice on what might be causing this discrepancy? I might be missing something obvious, but I can't think of anything else.

[image: Media query on the top menu is supposed to fire on 700px. The image shows screen being on 684px, and no media query is visible in the dev tools]

[image: Image shows being on 683px and the menu changes into a burger menu and media query appears as needing to fire on 700px]

Comment: Is there a scrollbar showing ? Share enouggh of your code that reproduce your issue, so we can see what you've done and maybe what's wrong with the code if not your browser.

Comment: The scrollbar is not hidden, if that is what you mean, so yes, it is displaying correctly. I will update the question with some code in a moment, and will also post screenshots from how it looks on any page I inspect online, for clarification.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I have edited the question with screenshots (sorry, the quality is real bad), but it shows the delay. The top menu is supposed to have a media query fire on 700px. The image shows the screen size being on 684px, and nothing happening (also no media query), and on 683px it switches to a burger menu and it shows in the dev tools that a media query fired on 700px. Is this clearer? 

edit: Also, this is taken from me inspecting the facebook page, just to show what is happening on my computer/browser.

Comment: the screenshot doesn't help, we cannot guess what CSS and structure you have, just your word that it goes wrong ;)

Comment: We need a [mcve] in your question to reproduce this. As G-Cyrillus noted, this could be from a scrollbar appearing, although in my experience they're usually 16px by default

Comment: @G-Cyrillus The screenshot it' on a facebook page, not the code I wrote. I am trying to explain since the opening post that it happens on every inspect, not just on the code I personally wrote.

Comment: okay, i have no hints or answers to help you, sorry. Hope someone else will be efficient here. ;)

Comment: @j0869 I get that, and thank you for trying, but I am not able to reproduce it otherwise. As I said in my opening post, on a different computer (Mac), the media queries fire perfectly fine. I have this literally on every inspection in dev tools. I was hoping that someone might have some similar experience. Otherwise, I just might reinstall or roll-back some win 10 updates, to see if my browsers will normalize.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That's ok, thank you for trying.

Comment: If I have the simplest possible setup - a div and a tall body so there is a scrollbar and media query at width 830px everything is behaving perfectly on Chrome/FF on Windows 10 so I'm afraid you do need to put some code into your question which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also getting this as of today - any browser on windows toggles breakpoints about 18px to early (or late depending on direction).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by the senior dev I work with.

The way it was solved by adding the following CSS to the code only on my laptop:

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
body { overflow-y: scroll }
```

It was definitely a scrollbar issue, as suspected from the beginning, that caused the dev tools to misbehave. The problem is still not reproducible on all Windows computers as I mentioned before, and was never reproduced on a Mac. This code only solves the problem locally for code I develop and inspect in the browser, and **does not** solve it for the complete dev tools, which are still firing incorrectly on page inspect.

The suspicion is it has to do with peripherals, but further testing is needed so I can compare the behavior.

The one extra pixel (16px + 1px) also disappeared after adding the CSS for the overflow, but also still persists in dev tools when inspecting code without the lines for overflow (a mystery for another day).

I would add that in Win 10 there is an option in the Ease of access settings, where you can toggle the hide/show the scroll bar, but that didn't do any difference in the dev tools.

Comment: Do you get this on every website you look at, or was it just the on the one site?

Have you managed to sort this issue since the question was asked?

Comment: @JakeWhiteley It's on every website, everywhere, which is why I kept repeating in my previous comments that it's not just the code I wrote )so I provided screenshots from inspecting Facebook in my OP). It has unfortunately not been solved further, I can only influence it when I write the code )with the solution I wrote above), but not when I inspect random webpages.

Comment: @JakeWhiteley I'd be very happy to hear if you make progress on this issue!

Comment: So I noticed this issue with devtools open - If I had a breakpoint at >=900px, as I resized my browser, devtools would report 872px as the window width when the breakpoint kicked in. In reality, it is just devtools reporting the wrong window width - the breakpoint is still kicking in at 900px, but for some reason devtools no longer reports scrollbar width as you resize. I noticed that if you open up the emulator, and set it to desktop, scrollbars ARE reported in the width shown as you resize which is very inconsistent behavior!

Comment: This also happens for me in edge, which makes sense as it is the same engine. The really odd thing is that it happens in firefox as well. I am asking other windows devs I know to test on their machines as well.

Comment: All other windows users I have asked also report this - I think its just default behavior now unfortunately.

Comment: @Jake Whiteley Thank you for the update. Indeed, the issue persists. If there are developments I will report here on this thread.